# Access local shell variables in vim

Tags: bash, vim

In vim I can access my bash environment variables such as $PWD and $PATH. I would like to know how to access my temporary shell variables in vim too.

For example, suppose I was in my terminal and define a variable `foo="bar"`. Then I enter vim and try to access this variable with the following command `:!echo $foo`, but it does not recognize this variable. From my understanding, vim starts a new shell each time a bash command is invoked and then closes it immediately after. Is there a way to use the same shell in vim that my local variable `foo` was defined in?

Comment: BTW, I think what you want is a "shell variable" (as opposed to an "environment variable"); a "local variable" is scoped to the execution of a single function, as opposed to being scoped to the shell in which it's run.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't interact with the parent shell from a subprocess it spawned (without that shell's active participation, which isn't reasonably/practically available in the scenario at hand) -- but you **can** export your variables to make them accessible to new shells started in child processes.

Running

```
set -a
```

...will make any variable defined going forward be automatically exported to the environment, even without an explicit `export` command.

---

Since (unlike the C `system()` function) vim's `system()` honors the `SHELL` environment variable, if `SHELL=/bin/bash` (or `:set shell=/bin/bash` has been run in vim), you can also invoke exported functions from vim. That is, if you define the function and export it as follows:

```
foo() { echo "bar"; }
export -f foo
```

...then you can invoke it with `!foo` from inside vim.

Even then, however, this is running in a new, transient shell instance, not the original parent process.

Answer (score 5):

## Explanation

Environment variables and shell variables are two entirely different concepts, but as we manipulate them in a similar way in bash, it's easy to get confused.

- Whenever a process is created (by fork), it may include an environment, given by its parent at fork-time. The child process may then access and modify its content. How this is done as a user depends on the program :

  - In vim, you can [access an environment variable](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-env) like this : `:echo $foo`
  - In bash, you can access it like this : `$ echo "$foo"`
  - In most programming languages, you can access it with a syntax coherent with the rest of the language, such as `ENV['foo']` in ruby
- On the other hand, a program may allocate memory for any internal use, but notably, it will quite often define and use variables. Once again, this depends on the program :

  - In vim, you would use [the :let command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:let) to assign an internal variable
  - In bash, you would assign a variable with `$ foo='bar'`, and then read it with `$ echo "$foo"`
  - In most programming languages, you have a variation of the `foo='bar'` syntax, sometimes with type declarations, etc

As you can see, bash **uses the same syntax to read an environment variable and one of its own private variables**, which can lead to some confusion.

When you execute `vim` from your bash shell, the environment is copied over from the parent process (bash) to the child (vim), but the private memory of bash (including the variables you may have defined) are not.

Thus, accessing them from the child process would require some inter-process communication mechanism, between parent and child. While technically doable, this option is not implemented in bash nor vim.

---

## Solution

In order for your variable to be accessible from vim (or any forked process, for that matter), you need it to be present in the environment of your vim process.

Several options to do that :

- `$ export foo='bar'` : This will mark your variable for export to the environment of subsequently executed commands. That's what you want in most cases.
- `$ foo='bar' vim` : This adds your variable to the environment of **this** vim command. Very useful for troubleshooting, or for one-liners.
- `$ set -a` : As you can see in [bash manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), this marks every subsequent definitions for export to the environment of subsequent commands. It's essentially equivalent to prepending every subsequent definition by `export`.

---

## To go further

- The question uses the `:!echo $foo` syntax to display the value of `foo`, which is yet another usecase. The `!` here is actually an escape sequence that allows you to execute a shell command from vim.

  However, vim cannot execute anything in the parent shell (the one you executed the `vim` command in), so it creates a new bash shell in a child process, executes `echo` in it, and displays the result.

  In the current case, the result is mostly the same, but it could easily be misleading in other situations, so it's important to understand what is happening here.
- There is [another vim syntax](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-env), using `expand`, that allows one to lookup variables : `:echo expand("$foo")`

  It however works entirely differently.

  If no internal variable named `foo` exists, vim will invoke a shell to look it up (similarly to what `!` would do).

  This options is **way** slower than an environment lookup, and not recommended for most usecases.

Comment: or `:e ^R=expand($myprojectdir)` meaning, when pressin <c-r> you can interactively expand the variable for usage in ex

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a value from your shell on the `:substitute` command, there's actually a way to do it.

I don't know if it solves your need but here we go.

Let's say we want to substitute `Mydir` by your `PWD`:

```
:s/Mydir/\=expand($PWD)/g
```