# Open shell variable (assigned with path) using vim editor

Tags: shell, vim, environment-variables

I am assigning a shell variable say `TEST1` in `.bashrc` like below:

```
TEST1='x/y'
```

In my Present directory (`pwd`), i have folders in following hierarchy:

```
pwd/x/y/ztext.c
```

I am at `pwd`. I want to open `ztext.c` file from bash shell by executing

```
vim $TEST1/ and Tab key
```

I expected shell will list ztext.c in screen. But it didnt. Since i know the file name, i entered like below:

`vim $TEST1/ztext.c`

vim was opening new file and not the existing file.

But `cd $TEST1` is moving to x/y folder path. Problem is only when executed with vim like mentioned above

Please correct me what am i doing wrong here.

Note : I tried export and set keyword for the TEST1 variable. It didnt help. Observation is same.

Comment: Why do you have a `.` at the end of your filename?

Comment: @politinsa I think you can ignore it as that's likely to be an artefact of my edit: the period at the end of OP's sentence. I am not 100% certain, though, so we should wait for clarifications.

Comment: In the same shell, what is the output of `$ echo $TEST1`?

Comment: @politinsa : It was a typo. Corrected it now

Comment: @romainl : it prints x/y

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996503/access-local-shell-variables-in-vim

Comment: @politinsa : Tried export and set keywords also. it didnt help.

Comment: Turn on `set -x` before invoking vim. What output do you get?

Comment: @user1934428 : Shell prints all the command executing logs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't why it's not working - I just did it on my machine. Below I show
exactly what I'm seeing in my terminal:

```
mattb@flat:~/mytest
$ l -R
.:
x/

./x:
y/

./x/y:
ztest.c
mattb@flat:~/mytest
$ export TEST1='x/y'
mattb@flat:~/mytest
$ vim $TEST1/
```

Pressing `Tab` expands to:

```
vim x/y/ztest.c
```